# How to create two table rows containing different columns?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the same width of `<tr>` of the two rows.

The first `<tr>` contains two `<td>` the second row contains only one `<td>` but as it is now, the second row is not with same width as the first one (see my script pleas)

How to keep the first row as it is and make the second one 100 width ?

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}

table tr td{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.second-row{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="first-row">
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second-row">
    <td>hello world</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 3):

use `colspan`

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}

table tr td{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.second-row{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="first-row">
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second-row">
    <td colspan="2">hello world</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```